# flash distance calculated in python

Tags: python, math, calculation

Define function of flash distance that takes an argument time interval (seconds) and calculates with formula:

```
the distance(in kilometers) = time interval(in seconds) * 330 / 1000.
```

Lightning distance in kilometers and return it. The distance shall be rounded to the whole number. Function of flash distance for the returned value must be rounded already.

I have program like this, but somethings is very wrong and I need help please. What and how I have to do?

```
def flash_distance (number_ms):
     flash_distance = (number_ms * 330/1000)
     round return (flash_distance * 330/1000)
   
distance_ms = 330

distance = int (input ("How many seconds it took seeing the lightning flash hearing?"))

print ("lightning distance in kilometers:" + str (flash_distance (distance_ms)))
```

Comment: Is  the **ms** in `distance_ms` supposed to mean this is **M**illi**S**econds format? Or just meaning `metres per sec`? Also mention what the correct expected output is versus what your function gives.

Comment: As commented lower you are applying twice formula on your number, that's why result is wrong I suppose

Comment: its not milliseconds is meter of seconds

Comment: @media76 okay. Wasn't sure if you needed to also multiply `ms * 1000` to convert that into seconds.

Answer (score 1):

I think the code below will settle your problem. In your code, `distance_ms` has been assigned to 330, so variable `distance` assigned by user will not work, which is generally not expected.

```
def flash_distance (number_ms): 
     flash_distance = (number_ms * 330/1000)  
     return round (flash_distance)

distance_ms = int (input ("How many seconds it took seeing the lightning flash hearing?"))

print ("lightning distance in kilometers:" + str (flash_distance (distance_ms)))
```

Comment: did not check anything but why * 330/1000 is applied twice? I think last line should be: return round(flash_distance)

Comment: Yes, The comment above is right, i just made a mistake, the 330/1000 should just be applied once. Thanks very much.

Comment: @media76 if the Answer is correct then mark as solved with `✔` icon. Thanks.